# Organize Redux action type and state

Tags: reactjs, types, redux, action, state

What is the best practice to organize my action types and state when I have a large app? One issue might be that I want to use the same name because it is a similar action and a similar state.

Just for the discussion: what if I wanted to update two titles, do I need to use a name convention like FIRST_TITLE and SECOND_TITLE for the action type and firstTitle and seccondTitle for the state?

I am open to better solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

In a large app, I've organized my code into modules, each with their own reducer, actions etc. Each module exports the action types and action creators, I use those exlusively and never just pass a string as type. This prevents any naming conflicts between modules - in fact I try to keep the action names short.

modules/items/actionTypes.js:

```
export const name = "items";

export const UPDATE_TITLE = `${name}/UPDATE_TITLE`;
```

modules/items/actions.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "./actionTypes";

export const updateTitle = (title) => ({
  type: actionTypes.UPDATE_TITLE,
  payLoad: title,
});
```

modules/items/reducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "./actionTypes";

const initialState = { title: "" };

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_TITLE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        title: action.payload,
      };
    }
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

modules/comments/actionTypes.js

```
export const name = "comments";

export const UPDATE_TITLE = `${name}/UPDATE_TITLE`;
```

modules/comments/actions.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "./actionTypes";

export const updateTitle = (title) => ({
  type: actionTypes.UPDATE_TITLE,
  payLoad: title,
});
```

modules/comments/reducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "./actionTypes";
import * as itemActionTypes from "../items/actionTypes";

const initialState = { title: "" };

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actionTypes.UPDATE_TITLE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        title: action.payload,
      };
    }
    case itemActionTypes.UPDATE_TITLE: {
      // Do something with the updated item title
    }
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

rootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { default as itemsReducer } from "modules/items/reducer";
import { default as commentsReducer } from "modules/comments/reducer";

export default combineReducers({
  items: itemsReducer,
  comments: commentsReducer,
});
```

EDIT: added reducers to answer comment

Comment: That is a great idea for the action types! Thank you very much.

If I get this right, the payLoad title is now one state in the store? If that is correct, what would you do to show two different titles at the same time? Do you have a name convention on states too?

Comment: I expanded the example to include reducers, hopefully this answers your question. I've found that using a convention of same file names in different modules really useful in keeping a large codebase maintainable and being able to quickly understand code written by different team members.

Comment: Ah, of course! I forgot about that part of what the combineReducers do: makes the two reducers, _items_ and _comments_, as two states in the store, each with a _title_ state. Thank you very much for clearifying!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [redux-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto). It generate actions and reducers from your file system.

We are using it in product for a large project and its has really helped bring down the complexity. It's nice that each transformation has its own file and this becomes your generated action name + async code co-located to the same file.

A summary:

It takes the ideas of reducer composition one step further. Where instead of having a file that represents your reducer and creating individual actions functions.

redux-auto's approaches to have folders with individual JS files representing each action/transformation on the state and dynamically exposing this as functions

example

```
└── store/
    ├──user/
    │  └── index.js
    │  └── changeName.js
    └──posts/
       └── index.js
       └── delete.js
```

Now from anyway in your app you can write

```
import actions from 'redux-auto'
...
actions.user.changeName({name:"bob"})
```

store/user/changeName.js

```
export default function (user, payload) {
    return Object.assign({},user,{ name : payload.name });
}
```

Thats is!

If you want to listen for redux actions in third-party reducers. You can use as loose quality check against the function.

```
action.type == actions.user.changeName // "USER/CHANGENAME"
```

For something more advanced you can even see if an action is owned by a specific reducer

```
// Returns true if it's an action specifically for user
if(action.type in actions.user)
```

You can read more on the [project page](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto#overview)